# protobuf-net: callback for deciding which objects to serialize

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, graph, protocol-buffers

I'm new to protobuf-net and am wondering whether there is a possibility to influence which objects are serialized if i have an object graph and want to serialize only parts of it. I think of some sort of callback or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two standard (used by other frameworks) patterns are supported for conditional serialization - if we have:

```
public Foo SomeProperty {get;set}
```

Then either of:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeSomeProperty() {...}
```

Or:

```
public bool SomePropertySpecified {
    get {...}
    set {...}
}
```

Should work fine. Return true to serialise, false to ignore. Depending on your target framework, it can also usually be non-public if desired.

Comment: Does that mean that the class that declares the property SomeProperty also needs to declare ShouldSerializeSomeProperty() or SomePropertySpecified, respectively?

Comment: @Ralf yes, that is the established, pre-existing (pre-dating protobuf-net) pattern that is currently supported. Note that via `RuntimeTypeModel` you can set the methods to be *any* instance methods / accessors on the object (without forcing any particular name convention), but yes: they must be declared on the type that owns the data. Of course, if this is inconvenient, you can use a *serialization surrogate* - protobuf-net supports swapping between 2 related representations during serialization, if some types in a model are less serialization-friendly than the rest